# SASS: Import a file from a specific directory

Tags: html, css, import, sass

My import for my font does not work in "internet-cafe/index.html" but works in "index.html"

Please help

My current sass in styles.sass:

```scss
@import url("../webfonts/ubuntu_regular/stylesheet.css");
```

Folder structure:

- internet cafe

  - index.pug
  - index.html
- styles

  - styles.sass
- webfonts

  - ubuntu_regular

    > stylesheet.css
- index.pug
- index.html

Comment: Are you compiling everything to a .css file? Is the imported CSS in that resulting compiled .css file? Use Developer Tools to inspect the resources that each page is pulling and see what CSS is missing.

Comment: i want to import the stylesheet from "ubuntu_regular" folder to the stylesheet of internet cafe. the font shows it works in index.html but not in internet-cafe/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If the file extension is `.css` the import is kept alone and therefore would only load if the file path is correct relative to the source of the stylesheet.

I don't where sass exports your stylesheets, but probably this is the source of your problem.

Comment: i uploaded my code online. it only gives me issues offline for some reason.

Comment: within localhost, a local url or a virtual host?

Comment: local host gives the issue, virtual host it is perfectly fine